# MAPR performance attributes are not contributing in the cluster for huge amount of data

Tags: hbase, mapr

We are facing performance issue in HPE Data fabric database (MapR DB). Number of GET Batch calls to MapR DB in our cluster is huge (around 70%) but throughput of the calls are very poor.

The tables are distributed but still we are seeing this issue.

When checking the HPE Data fabric documentation, we came across this configuration - mfs.cache.lru.sizes. The supported value of this configuration is inode:3:meta:6:small:27:dir:15:db:20:valc:3. We need more info about this configuration

```
>     what is the use of each config value i.e. inode, meta, small, dir, db and valc    Any tuning suggestion to increase the performance of
> table get operation.
```

https://docs.datafabric.hpe.com/62/ReferenceGuide/mfs.conf.html

Answer (score 0):

In general, adjusting the priorities and allocations for caching in a multi-use cluster is not something to take lightly.

You should contact your support contact to deal with this. Stackoverflow does not have qualified people for handling this kind of question.

HPE Ezmeral DF Customer Support ezmeral_software_support@hpe.com

You can also reach out to me directly if you need forwarding.